# In the context of block-encoding, what does $|0\rangle\otimes I$ represent?

Tags: mathematics, linear-algebra

New to quantum and ran into the block-encoding. Having a bit of trouble understanding $|0\rangle \otimes I$.

$|0\rangle$ is just a vector but $I$ is an $n$ by $n$ matrix?  Not clear how vector can be tensorproducted with a matrix?  I know I am missing something here.

Any help could be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You should treat $|v\rangle$ as a $m\times 1$ matrix, where $m$ is the dimension of the Hilbert space in which the vector lives.

Comment: Could you add the reference to the paper where you copied the definition above about block encodings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably best done with an example. Let's consider a $4\times 4$ matrix $U$ which acts on two qubits. The $|0\rangle\otimes I$ is equivalent to
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)\otimes\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
(if you don't know where this comes from, go back to the definition of the tensor product). This is a $4\times 2$ matrix, meaning it's the right size for you to pre-multiply by $U$. Similarly,
$$
\langle 0|\otimes I\equiv \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
so that, overall your matrix $A$ comes out as $2\times 2$ (it's the action of what happens to the second qubit if the first qubit starts and ends in state $|0\rangle$).

Comment: Thank you.   A follow-up question if you don't mind.   I assume other elements in the 4x4 matrix are zero and U has the same rank as A?  If so,  how U can be a unitary?  The paper says A doesn't need to be Unitary.

Comment: No, I think you have to fill in the rest of the matrix $U$ so that it becomes unitary.

Comment: You may want to look at: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/5167/when-can-a-matrix-be-extended-into-a-unitary