# Why are all the eigenvalues of a "Hermitian block-encoding" equal to $\pm1$?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, unitarity, linear-algebra

I was looking at the paper : https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11649 and the eigenvalue discussion is not clear to me.

Block-encoding is a general technique to encode a nonunitary matrix on a quantum computer. Let $A \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ be an $n$-qubit Hermitian matrix. If we can find an $(m+$ $n)$-qubit unitary matrix $U \in \mathbb{C}^{M N \times M N}$ such that
$$
U_{A}=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot
\end{array}\right)
$$
holds, i.e., $A$ is the upper-left matrix block of $U_{A}$, then we may get access to $A$ via the unitary matrix $U_{A}$. In particular,
$$
A=\left(\left\langle 0^{m}\right| \otimes I_{n}\right) U_{A}\left(\left|0^{m}\right\rangle \otimes I_{n}\right)
$$

**If $U_{A}$ is Hermitian, it is called a Hermitian block-encoding. In particular, all the eigenvalues of a Hermitian block-encoding $U_{A}$ are $\pm 1$.**

It is not clear why all the eigenvalues are  $\pm 1$?  any guidance?
Thanks

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5167/55

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$U_A$ is defined to be a unitary matrix in the paper and your question. Consider the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the general unitary matrix $U$ given by $U|\lambda\rangle=\lambda|\lambda\rangle$.

$$U|\lambda\rangle=\lambda|\lambda\rangle$$
$$\langle\lambda| U^{\dagger}=\lambda^*\langle\lambda|$$
$$\langle\lambda| U^{\dagger}U|\lambda\rangle=\lambda\lambda^*\langle\lambda|\lambda\rangle$$
$$\rightarrow |\lambda|^2=1$$

In the paper it also says "If $U_A$ is Hermitian then it is called Hermitian Block Encoding" on the first line of page three. Now obviously we know that the eigenvalues of a Hermitian Matrix are real.

Therefore we know the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of the matrix $U_A$ are real and have magnitude 1. There are only 2 such numbers; $+1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @Betrand Einstein IV  ,  Ah. Thanks. Somehow the simple unitary was slipped out of my mind and was looking at the rightway.  Thanks!