# Minimum number of ancilla qubits to unitarily simulate a measurement?

Tags: circuit-construction, measurement

Let's say I have a ket which is a momentum eigenket $| p \rangle$ and then I measure the position and obtain $|x' \rangle$.

$$ | p \rangle = \int | x \rangle \langle x | p \rangle dx  \to | x' \rangle $$

My question is what is the minimum number of ancilla qubits required to simulate this transformation unitarily?

Note: Since the cardinality of kets involved here is $\aleph_1$ I am unaware how to implement [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9085/5045)

Comment: do you think this is a measurement that you could actually, physically, do?

Comment: Sorry do mean measure the momentum and then position?

Comment: No, I mean do you think it's possible to *exactly* perform a position measurement?

Comment: Ah well I am aware in relativistic QM the dirac Delta function is a guassian ... If that's where this discussion is headed?

Comment: Regarding the cardinality of the kets...check Moretti's [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/98726).

Comment: By the way, I don't see how relativistic QM was hinted any way in DW's comment. He just meant that an exact position measurement is meaningless in QM; we only take measurement in an interval (more rigorously, a Borel measurable subset of the reals).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While talking about knowing the position *exactly* is a nice theoretical ideal, in practice, you cannot do that. You'll really be asking: "In which 'bin' of width $\delta x$ where $x$ spans from $x_{\min}$ to $x_{\max}$ is the particle confined to?". This means that there's $(x_{\max}-x_{\min})/\delta x$ bins, and so you basically need
$$
\log_2\left((x_{\max}-x_{\min})/\delta x\right)
$$
qubits to represent that information. Hence, this is the number of ancillas you would need.

Comment: Does this mean the cardinality of the Hamiltonian (with the ancilla qubits) is aleph 1 ? (Sorry on phone)

Comment: Or is it aleph 2 ?

Comment: I'd add that exactly measuring a particle's position is nonsensical even in theory, as a single $x\in \Bbb R$ has measure zero. Intuitively, that's zero probably for finding a particle at any specific location.

Comment: @MoreAnonymous: 1. You're discretizing the space and performing the simulation with qubits; infinite cardinalities aren't relevant here (it's finite-dimensional after the discretization!). 2. Even in the infinite-dimensional case, the exact cardinality type is irrelevant to the physics at hand (Motl had written a [blog post](https://motls.blogspot.com/2014/02/cardinality-of-bases-doesnt-matter-for.html?m=1) precisely on this topic; also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/127072)).

Comment: @MoreAnonymous: [cont.] 3. Regardless, if you're still interested in the cardinality from a purely theoretical perspective, it's $\aleph_0$ for $L^2(\Bbb R)$ (cf. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/64870)). However, in this case, DW is performing the simulation using a finite number of basis states. It should be easy to calculate the dimension of the Hamiltonian matrix given that you know the number of qubits exactly.